# Batch Execution Exception when run in sequence

Tags: batch

I am getting the below exception when I am running batches in sequence. That is, I am calling another method to create next batch once the first batch is in it's finish method.

**Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.**

I am sure we are using latest version of the Batchable interface.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely problem is the Salesforce API version that the `Batchable` class is set to. That needs to be >= 27 for the batch chaining from the `finish` method to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hey It works only in API version 27.
Change API version to 27. Will work for you. :)

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any proof/link to official docs about that? I have 1 batch starting out of `finish()` method of another and it works like a charm (API v 23)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the version to 26 and it worked :) It was initially 25 fyi.